# is it possible to convert eSata to USB 3.0

Tags: usb, esata

I have an laptop with several an eSATA slot, the laptop has no USB 3.0 slots. I was wondering if its possible to use the eSATA slot as an USB 3.0 slot with an converter.

I did some google-ing and found some hubs, but its not clear if they are USB 3.0 to eSata or the other way around.

Has someone an idea if this possible ?

Comment: Are you sure your laptop doesn't have an expresscard slot? Details here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpressCard. They were quite common before USB 3 and would be a better way of adding ports.

Comment: Have you looked?  If it exists it is sold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot go from an eSATA connection to USB only the other way around I'm afraid. I verified this a couple of days ago on another question.

You can of course get external disk housings that take both connections if you only want disks.

eSATA however only supports storage, it doesn't support all of the other things that USB can do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an eSATA port with USB devices because it does not communicate with a USB controller.

However, eSATAp (with a "p") ports exist which are capable of accepting both USB and eSATA plugs. [This Wikipedia.org article may help you identify if your laptop has a combo port (see article photo)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESATAp)